# In HTML - how to build columns that withstand changing document direction?

Tags: html, css

I want to create three columns. If I use float: left, and then change the document from LTL to RTL, this means the order of columns from left to right stay the same.

I know about the column-count css property, but this doesn't work in IE9.

Tables are also an option. Is that considered bad markup?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the columns which would also be RTL, you can use `inline-blocks` instead of `floats` for column layout: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/YmkbJ/

I used `span`s so I won't have to use hacks for IE, but if you'd like to use `div`s — use Conditional Comments with `{display:inline;zoom:1;}` to fix it so block-level tags would behave like inline-blocks.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't get the divs to be on the same line if their contents are not equal (for example one of them contains a textarea and the others several inputs).

Comment: Ah, yeah, if you need to align them, you can use `vertical-align`: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/YmkbJ/20/ you can even align them to the bottoms if you need: and you can't do this with floats. If you have any others issues with inline-block layouts — tell me, I'll try to fix them )

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 has the option, to display columns, but this is currently not implemented across all browsers. For example Wikipedia uses that already for the [references-section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree#References).

Those columns work for both text directions.

```
ul.two_column {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 2em;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 2em; }
```

See also:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn

Comment: Yes I know about this property, as far as I know this isn't supported in IE9 right?

Comment: Right—I didn't test it myself, but heres a compatibility table:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn